# Typescript assigns an empty string instead of a boolean

Tags: typescript

Given this typescript (2.7.2) interface:

```
export interface A {
  b?: string;
  c?: boolean;
}
```

This will print boolean 'false' as expected:

```
let a: A = {b: ''};
if (a.b && a.b.length > 0) {
  a.c = true;
} else {
  a.c = false;
}
console.log(a.c);
```

However, this prints an empty '' string:

```
let a: A = {b: ''};
a.c = a.b && a.b.length > 0;
console.log(a.c);
```

I'm a bit confused here. The second example should behave like the first one, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.b && a.b.length > 0` which is equivalent to `"" && false` because empty string evaluates falsy. Expression `"" && false` evaluates to `""`. that is why `a.c` is `""`.

Refactor it like this,

```
a.c = a.b && a.b.length > 0 ? true : false
```

Comment: Good to know: IntelliJ is not smart enough to handle this. It issues a warning that this code can be simplyfied.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a Javascript truthy/falsy issue. The `&&` operator will return the value of one of the operands. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

And specifically for `&&` :

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

In your case `""` is a falsy value, so it can be converted to false. If you want to ensure you get a boolean use `!!` (ie. double negation)

```
let a: A = {b: ''};
a.c = !!(a.b && a.b.length > 0);
console.log(a.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaning on the reply from @nrgwsth you can refactor further while keeping your structure by replacing `a.b` with `!!a.b` in your conditions like this:

```
let a: A = {b: ''};
a.c = !!a.b && a.b.length > 0;
console.log(a.c);
```

Applying `!a.b` converts `a.b` to its boolean negative, applying `!!a.b` gives you the positive boolean version of the evaluation.